# How can I use a Muse param to do a boolean comparison in order to run a JS function?

Tags: javascript, muse

I need Adobe Muse widget that will run a function based on true or false.

Maybe this could help http://adobe-muse.github.io/MuCowDocs/#id-bool-

```
<parameters>
    <bool name="rwindow" label="Resize Window" defaultValue="true">
        <trueVal value="true"/>
        <falseVal value="false"/>
    </bool>
</parameters>
```

I need something like this:

```
if(true) {
    alert('function on');
    } else if(false) {
    alert('function off');
}
```

Thank you very much for you time and patience.

Comment: And the problem is....What is `{param_wresize}`? What is that random bool mark-up?

Comment: What, exactly, is the issue that you're having?

Comment: Function wont run, nothing happens.

Comment: So you have a form and if something is true you want to run a function?

Comment: This is adobe muse widget and I see other use this {param_name}, yes SharpCode

Comment: So wouldn't it be smart to tag it with that and not with useless tags like syntax and selector and function?

Comment: if(wresize == "true" ) <= this also doesn't work.

Comment: Is adobe muse the new dreamweaver?

Comment: With Adobe Muse you can create a website without writing a code. Now I'm trying to add custom code. Script is working well but I can't connect it with widget form.

Comment: I think we need to see your full `<HTMLWidget>` tag. For example, jQuery is only accessible in `<bodyEndHTML>`. It would be good to see how you are building you entire widget.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/QWEVFcpHzURNHSrPWheUzN @sifriday

Comment: Thanks. You have a few syntax errors. Also this reminds me a bit of the XY problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Your question is, I think, "How do I reload my page via a Muse widget when the windows resizes?". Or if not can you explain more about what this widget is trying to do?

Comment: I think in the end we have turned this into a useful question. Thanks Mukos for working with all the feedback proposed above. For everyone who originally understandably downvoted this, would you consider revising your downvote? I ask this because (1) the Muse docs don't exactly explain how to use params in JavaScript code and (2) there are few Muse questions on SO, so this question might actually be genuinely insightful, now that it is correctly tagged, titled, explained and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general observations.. You have some syntax errors and you don't need the `if(false)`. That will never be evaluated and at that point there is no function to return from. And your script tag is missing a closing `>`.

As of jQuery 1.7, `.on` is preferred to `.bind`.

To reload from the server, not cache, you need `reload(true)`

Your timeout code looks OK.

I'm not a Muse expert, but you need to use {param} notation to get the params into your code.

And as discovered by working through a simpler example (attached below), to use a Muse param in a string comparison, you need to wrap it in quotes: `if ("{param_wresize}" == "true")` This presumably generates the JS,

```
if ("true" == "true") // Evaluates to true
```

or in the case of the other param setting,

```
if ("false" == "true") // Evaluates to false
```

So we get something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HTMLWidget name="Resize Window" formatNumber="2" localization="none"
    creator="Mukos" defaultWidth="30" defaultHeight="30"
    isResizable="false">

    <parameters>
        <separator/>
        <bool name="wresize" label="Resize Window" defaultValue="true">
            <trueVal value="true"/>
            <falseVal value="false"/>
        </bool>
    </parameters>

    <bodyEndHTML>
        <![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
                if ("{param_wresize}" == "true" ) {
                    $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
                        if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
                        window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
                            this.location.reload(true);
                        }, 200);
                    });
                }
            </script>
        ]]>
    </bodyEndHTML>
</HTMLWidget>
```

You can try that and see if it works, but I can't say it will or not. This is what made me suggest the XY problem in the comments above. You have asked quite specifically about how to run a function based on a parameter value. But what's the actual problem you're trying to solve? You might be going about it the wrong way. Any info you have about your intentions would be useful.

For example, the pattern of reloading on a resize might be to fix some kind of layout issue, maybe to do with a responsive design. Muse isn't great at building responsive websites. There might be some other way of tackling this problem.

---

Simpler version proposed by Mukos. Try it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HTMLWidget name="Resize Window" formatNumber="2" localization="none"
    creator="Mukos" defaultWidth="30" defaultHeight="30"
    isResizable="false">

    <parameters>
        <separator/>
        <bool name="wresize" label="Resize Window" defaultValue="true">
            <trueVal value="true"/>
            <falseVal value="false"/>
        </bool>
    </parameters>

    <bodyEndHTML>
        <![CDATA[
            <script type="text/javascript">
                if ("{param_wresize}" == "true" ) {
                    alert("true");
                }
                else {
                    alert("false");
                }
            </script>
        ]]>
    </bodyEndHTML>
</HTMLWidget>
```

Comment: It is not working. Let's forget about this function. We can do it with simple alert('it is working');
I have add this:
<script type="text/javascript">
 $({param_wresize} == "false").ready(function(){
 alert('it is working');
});
</script>

And it is working if it's true or not.

Here is [link](http://adobe-muse.github.io/MuCowDocs/)

Comment: I wonder if the problem is how exactly does Muse substitute the value of {param_wresize} ? If it is a straight text substitution, then we probably need to try `if ("{param_wresize}" == "true")` to create a valid JS comparison. Some edited code above for you to try.

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much! I really apriciate your help! @sifriday

Comment: brilliant! That means we can probably work out how to do the resize function as well; I'll edit my first example above to include the extra `"{param_wresize}"`